# Android Textview - letters and numbers alignment

Tags: android, string, textview, alignment

i want to display long String in TextView, and part of the string (letters), is in the right side, and numbers appears in the left one, how can i display the numbers in right??

thanks alot.

Comment: like @njzk2 suggested create two text views and add android:gravity = "right" in the numbertextview part in the xml layout

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/numbers"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="left" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/letters"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="right" />
</LinearLayout>
```